# Parametrize dynamic SQL with temporary table inside

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I create dynamic SQL with parameters `@FilePath` and `@WorksheetName` for query below WITHOUT creating a temporary table before? I cannot create the table because I do not know the count of columns in the file.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #OLD_REPORT 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0; 
                Database=C:\OLD_REPORT.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1', 
                'SELECT * FROM [Worksheet1$]')
```

Something like

```
declare @sql varchar(2000)
set @sql = 'SELECT ... INTO #OLD_REPORT ...' + @FilePath + '...' + @WorksheetName + '...'
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

doesn't work because of the `#OLD_REPORT` table (cannot run `SELECT * FROM #OLD_REPORT`)

Comment: You can use `##OLD_REPORT ` in dynamic query.

Comment: Why you cannot select from it? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you do not know what to expect from that file how SQL Server will know that?

You can use `INTO` syntax to create a table if you specify all column names in the `select` statement.

I was thinking how to help you.
You can try to use CSV files instead of Excel. Then you will be able to load whole row at the time and then you can determine number of columns, column names and dynamically build temp tables and fill them in.

However, that might be easier to do in .NET.

Comment: I disagree.
You can use `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM Table` without specifying the column names.

Comment: I did not say "You MUST always specify columns when you do `SELECT INTO`". In case you do it from an existing table SQL already knows column names from it. Right?

Comment: If you select into from existing table SQL knows the column names, right.
the query below is still valid anyway without specifying column names and its not from existing table;
`SELECT *
INTO #OLD_REPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; 
    Database=C:\OLD_REPORT.xlsx;
    HDR=YES; 
    IMEX=1', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')`

Comment: Besides i do not mean to fight or anything but if anyone say
You can 'a' if you 'b' then i translate it to the math

A if and only if b
which means a is true only if b is true

it would be better if you said
You can use `INTO` syntax to create a table if you specify all column names in the `select` statement OR in some other rare circumstances.

Comment: In the end I will stick to the global temporary tables if I will ever need to do this query asked in first post.

Comment: In your original request you are trying to get a silver bullet like: "I want to be able to load ANY data into the SQL in ANY format with any unpredictable names and SQL Server has to figure out all that info and create tables for me without even compiling the query...."